# extracting string from a table in word document using python win32com

Tags: python, win32com, os.path

I am trying to extract a string from a table in word document using win32 and concatenating it using os.join. But I am getting a weird output. Following is my entire code:

```
import win32com.client as win32
import os
 word = win32.Dispatch("Word.Application")
 word.Visible = 0
 word.Documents.Open("E:\pyauto\sample.doc")
 doc = word.ActiveDocument
 table = doc.Tables(11)
 for i in range(2 , table.Rows.Count):
    Path=table.Cell(Row = i,Column = 2).Range.Text  
    dir_base="E:"+'\\'
    base_filename=Path.strip()
    filename_suffix = '.zip'
    absPath=os.path.join(dir_base,base_filename+filename_suffix)
    print absPath
```

**Actual Output:**

```
.zipolder\file
```

The string mentioned in the document is,

```
folder\file
```

**Desired output:**

```
E:\folder\file.zip
```

Please help me out with this.

Comment: Please include the actual output and the desired output and explain why the former is "weird."

Comment: there is another question, which mentions exactly this output https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50975677/remove-backslash-while-constructing-absolute-path-with-os-path-join

Comment: can you print base_filename before doing os.path.join?

Comment: Printing base_filename is giving 'folder\file' as output.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove backslash while constructing absolute path with os.path.join()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50975677/remove-backslash-while-constructing-absolute-path-with-os-path-join)

Comment: How is it a duplicate if only the output is same

Comment: It seems weird to show proof for these kind of arguments. Anyway, I feel both questions uses same variables and same statements but except instead of folder2, you put `file` which doesn't make anysense for a `zipped` folder.  Also, both questions are posted within 30 min timespan and your code is actually written based on `one of the solutions` for that question.

Comment: Good observation. That was previously posted by me. but after incorporating those changes I was facing this new issue. But this is an entirely different topic.so I had to post it again.

Comment: I think it has to do with Path is being set equal to something undesirable. I set Path equal to `'folder\\file'` and the output I got was `E:\folder\file.zip`

Comment: But since it's duplicated now my views reduced and I am not getting any answers

Comment: @pavan, if you are the one who posted last question then you shouldn't ask here, instead you can post/comment there itself and you are facing same problem in two instances.